# Dependent and independent variables of a differential equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

$$\theta'' + \delta\theta'+\sin\theta = F\cos(\omega t)$$

I am trying to write it as a first order equation, and state the dependent, independent and parameters in the ODE.

I have written it as:

$$\theta'=v$$

$$v'=F\cos(\omega t)-\delta v-\sin\theta$$

How do I know which are the dependent and independent variables?

Am I correct in saying that it is non-autonomous and non-linear?

Comment: $t$ is the independent variable, $\theta$ and $v$ are dependent. Everything else is correct.

Comment: @Artem Can you explain why?

Comment: Because $v$ and $\theta$ depend on $t$, and $t$ does not depend on anything.